# panda dataframe aggregate by ID and date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate a dataframe by both ID and date. Suppose I had a dataframe:

```
  Publish date  ID  Price
0   2000-01-02   0     10
1   2000-01-03   0     20
2   2000-02-17   0     30
3   2000-01-04   1     40
```

I would like to aggregate the value by ID and date (frequency = 1W) and get a dataframe like:

```
  Publish date  ID  Price
0   2000-01-02   0     30
1   2000-02-17   0     30
2   2000-01-04   1     40
```

I understand it can be achieved by iterating the ID and using grouper to aggregate the price. Is there any more efficient way without iterating the IDs? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with aggregate `sum`, but not sure about frequency of `Grouper` (because all looks different like in question):

```
df['Publish date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Publish date'])

df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Publish date'),'ID'], sort=False)['Price']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  Publish date  ID  Price
0   2000-01-02   0     10
1   2000-01-09   0     20
2   2000-02-20   0     30
3   2000-01-09   1     40
```

---

```
df['Publish date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Publish date'])

df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W-Mon', key='Publish date'),'ID'], sort=False)['Price']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  Publish date  ID  Price
0   2000-01-03   0     30
1   2000-02-21   0     30
2   2000-01-10   1     40
```

Or:

```
df['Publish date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Publish date'])

df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7D', key='Publish date'),'ID'], sort=False)['Price']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  Publish date  ID  Price
0   2000-01-02   0     30
1   2000-02-13   0     30
2   2000-01-02   1     40
```